Why useEffect runs ervery time when component <PostList/> loaded from Home component
I have working on a Social media Application and getting stuck with this.
Inside src > component > PostListI have useduseEffect``` with empty dependency array but whenever I went createPost inside SideBar and come Back useEffect again render that causes me not able to add any extra post .
https://github.com/santukumar01/learningreact/tree/main/Social Media App - version- 2
How to resolve this and why every useEffect is runnung .

Please include relevant code in the question as formatted text.

Code file  is big  therefore i have  included the github repo for better understanding.Is there any other infromation you want please  write it . i will provide it.

Your useEffect is re-running because the components are remounting every time selectedTab in your Sidebar.jsx changes:
{selectedTab === "home" ? <PostList /> : <CreatePost />}

To fix this I recommend moving your data fetch into a more stable place like context or an external state management solution like zustand, then passing the data as props to PostList.


One way to prevent unnecessary re-renders of the PostList component is
to use a key prop on it and change the key whenever you want it to
remount. Since you're using tabs to switch between different views
("home" and "Create Post"), you can use the selected tab as a key for
the PostList component. This way, whenever the selected tab changes,
React will treat it as a different component and remount it, causing
the use effect to run only when necessary.
Most of the time, I use a key in the map, and I can use it in the component, the key works
similarly
to react. memo. when you change the tab and increase the key value, the
the component renders after the component check key is changed.

function App() {
  const [selectedTab, setSelectedTab] = useState("home");
  const [postListKey, setPostListKey] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    setPostListKey(prevKey => prevKey + 1);
  }, [selectedTab]);

  return (
    <PostContexProvider>
      <div className="app-container">
        <SideBar setSelectedTab={setSelectedTab} selectedTab={selectedTab} />
        <div className="content">
          <Header />
          {selectedTab === "home"? <PostList key={postListKey} /> : <CreatePost />}
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </div>
    </PostContexProvider>
  );
}


Note, that I think you are struggling, and I reviewed the whole code, needs more improvement, especially in the createPost component. thanks
